# Spring integration acknowledge message processing back to previous service

Tags: spring, spring-integration

In Spring Integration, I have a chain of services, like this:

```
message -> A -> B -> C -> D -> ... -> output
```

This works fine. I want to make each of the services asynchronous and to make them pessimistic. Each of them will get a message, process it and send it to the next service in chain. However, it will not wait till the whole chain finishes. It will continue processing the next message and so on. Standard async here.

However, let's say service B is slower than A and that it accumulates 10k messages in its inbound channel queue and at that time the system crashes. I want to be able to restore the system by figuring out where I left and re-processing the messages. For that reason, I want each of the services to know which of the messages it processed was successfully consumed by the following service. The difference between sent vs. processed.

My idea is to do it similar to this (fancy ascii):

```
-> A --> B -> C -> ...
   ^     |
   | ack |
   \-----/
```

That is, A will send to B, B will process and when it is done successfully it will send an ack to A. A will then remove that particular message from the store, so that the next time it runs, it will not re-process it. I thought I would just put a splitter after B that will call a different method on service A (i.e. `ackProcessed`).

Is this how it should be done in SI or is there another way I'm missing? I'm primarily asking for a confirmation I'm not missing something supported out-of-the-box or something that will not force me to create a splitter after each of the services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't be a splitter; more likely a pub-sub channel and the ack would probably want to go to a different method in A (i.e. a different service-activator that references the same bean, different method; and the methods share some state).

An easier solution would be to use a persistent message channel (e.g. JMS, RabbitMQ, or a message-store-backed QueueChannel). That way the framework will take care of everything for you.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Note that I don't care about losing acks on shutdown. Can you clarify how using a persistent message channel would change things? Also, why wouldn't the splitter work? I could split the message to two destinations (A and C in this case), possibly adding a transformer between it and A (if splitters cannot also do the tranformation). Wouldn't that work as expected?

Comment: It means that once A has sent its message it doesn't care any more because, if the system crashes, when the system is run the next time, any queued messages will still be there and will be handled by B. A splitter is to split a (e.g. collection) into individual messages, or to, say, split an Order into OrderLines. A splitter is not used to send the same message to 2 consumers.

Comment: Thanks Gary, got what you meant now. I assume with pub-sub channel I'd add a bridge afterwards to make it a pollable one, as I want services to be called asynchronously, correct?

Comment: Yes; or you can add a `task-executor` to the pub-sub channel and the "queue" is then inside the task executor rather than the channe.